# XSL Node Traversal

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am working on creating an XSL document that will be used to create some HTML based upon an XML file. I am very new to the XML/XSL world and I am struggling with even asking the right questions. Following is a rough representation of the XML file:

```
<Item elemID="1" material="oak"></Item>
<Item elemid="2" material="cedar"></Item>
<Item elemid="3" material="spruce"></Item>
<ColourType primary_object="1" secondary_object="100"></ColourType>
<ColourType primary_object="2" secondary_object="101"></ColourType>
<ColourType primary_object="3" secondary_object="102"></ColourType>
<Colour id="100" name="Blue"></Colour>
<Colour id="101" name="Red"></Colour>
<Colour id="102" name="Yellow"></Colour>
```

I am able to get the `<Item>` node without problem. The challenge I am having is figuring out how I can look up the `<ColourType>` node and in turn the `<Colour>` node.

Part of my XSL looks like:

```
<xsl:variable name="ItemRef" select="//tcplm:Item/tcplm:GSIdentity[@elemId=$occrid]"/>
```

That gives me the `<Item>` node, but I'm stumped as to how I can navigate or lookup the `<ColourType>` node.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Can someone help me insert my sample XML file? It seems to have been dropped when I saved my post.

Comment: done, but you can use the code button when inserting code or tags. Select the code/tag and click the button with the 01 on it..

Comment: what is target html you want to reach ?

Comment: @Gaby, thanks for helping with the code insert. I am ultimately hoping to get the <Colour> Name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
<xsl:variable name="clr" select="//Colour[@id=//ColourType[@primary_object=$occrid]/@secondary_object]/@name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is FAQ: **Whenever there is cross reference, you should use keys**

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key

> Keys provide a way to work with
>   documents that contain an implicit
>   cross-reference structure. The ID,
>   IDREF and IDREFS attribute types in
>   XML provide a mechanism to allow XML
>   documents to make their
>   cross-reference explicit. XSLT
>   supports this through the XPath id
>   function.

Suppose these keys declarations:

```
<xsl:key name="kColourTypeByPrimary" match="ColourType" use="@primary_object"/>
<xsl:key name="kColourById" match="Colour" use="@id"/>
```

Then you could select the `Colour` for your context `Item` with this XPath/XSLT expression:

```
key('kColourById',key('kColourTypeByPrimary',@elemid)/@secondary_object)
```